# Valuation with values in a semiring?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ct.category-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

The notion of "valuation" on a ring $R$ is peculiar in that as typically presented, it is really two notions, neither of which subsumes the other.

1. A valuation can be a homomorphism $v: (R,\times) \to \Gamma \cup \{0\}$ where $\Gamma$ is an ordered abelian group, which preserves and reflects 0 and satisfies the *ultratriangle inequality* $v(a+b) \leq max(v(a),v(b))$ with equality when $a\neq b$.
2. A valuation can be a homomorphism $(R,\times) \to \mathbb [0,\infty)$  which preserves and reflects 0 and satisfies the *triangle inequality* $v(a+b) \leq v(a)+v(b)$.

For example large function fields tend to fall under (1) but not (2) while $\mathbb R$ with its usual norm falls under (2) but not (1).

The justification for having a bifurcative definition like this seems to simply be that in an arbitrary ordered abelian group, one doesn't have an additional operation available to formulate the triangle inequality.

But it seems to me that there is a natural common generalization of these two definitions:

**Definition:** Let $R$ be a ring and $\Gamma$ an ordered semiring. A valuation $v: R \to \Gamma$ is a multiplicative homomorphism preserving and reflecting 0 satisfying the *triangle inequality* $v(a+b) \leq v(a)+v(b)$.

Then (1) above is recovered by taking $+$ to be $max$, and (2) is recovered with the usual addition on $[0,\infty)$.

**Question:** Has anybody written about valuation theory with values in a semiring before?

Comment: (This is not an answer) You may be interested to know that Lawvere studied generalized metric spaces (and your definition is basically a ring object in that category, i.e. a monoid object in the category of abelian group objects in that category). A Lawvere metric space is a category enriched over the monoidal category $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ (poset category, with addition the monoid operation). He does away with the symmetry axiom, but we pick it up when we take abelian group objects in this category, to get normed abelian groups. Anyways, this construction works quite generally.

Comment: Right, thanks. I think there's one difference -- Lawvere allows distances to be infinite.

Comment: For instance, we can switch $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ for an "ordered semiring". I have taken this study as a project of mine, and will upload to the archiv some time in the next 6 months or so. (oh, and yes there is that difference, plus that we drop the hausdorff / definiteness condition $||x|| = 0 \implies x = 0$).

Comment: The archimedian and nonarchimedian norms seem to "fit together" in a way governed by the Riemann-Roch theorem. For $\mathbb{Q}$, $\prod_{p \in \text{Spec}(\mathbb{Q}) \cup \{ \infty \} } |x|_p = 1$, so that the archimedian norm $| \cdot |_{\infty}$ "just offsets" the others. Note that $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ plays the role of the Riemann sphere, so that its genus is $0$. If some definition like yours encompases both archimedian and nonarchimedian norms, it might also clarify what is going on with this "balancing act".