# Generalization of Ostrowski's Theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory, norms

Let $\Lambda$ be a totally ordered set with two binary operations $+$ and $\cdot$ on it, such that:

1) $+$ is associative, has a unit $0$, and is symmetric.

2) $\cdot$ is associative, has a unit $1$, and is symmetric.

3) $a \cdot (b + c) = a \cdot b + a \cdot c$.

Let $\nu : \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \Lambda$ be a surjective function such that

1) $\nu(0) = 0$ and $\nu(a + b) \leq \nu(a) + \nu(b)$

2) $\nu(1) = 1$ and $\nu(ab) = \nu(a)\nu(b)$.

3) $\nu(x) = 0 \implies x = 0$.

> **Question:** What other conditions are necessary for the conclusion of Ostrowski's theorem to hold? That is, what are conditions such that $\nu$ is equivalent to a $p$-adic norm $| \cdot |_p$ or the archimedian norm $| \cdot |_{\infty}$?

---

Notes:

1) In Ostrowski's theorem, we assume that $\Lambda = (\mathbb{R}, +, \cdot )$ to begin with. Here I start with an ambient $\Lambda$, and it suffices to show $\Lambda = (\mathbb{R}, +, \cdot)$

2) If, for each $a , b \in \Lambda$, with $a \neq 0$, there is $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$ such that $an > b$, then we can embedd $\Lambda$ in $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$. This reduces to Ostrowski's theorem. However, I expect there are  weaker things one can assume.

3) If $a \leq b \iff a + b = b$ for $a , b \in \Lambda$, then the norm is nonarchimedian and we have reduced to Ostrowski's theorem.

Comment: Are you currently making no assumptions that connect the ordering on $\Lambda$ and the algebraic operations other than $\nu(a + b) \leq \nu(a) + \nu(b)$?

Comment: @user44191 I was thinking about that. It's true- that is the only assumption I have made connecting the two. It seems like not enough.

Comment: A candidate assumption: $0 \in \Lambda$ is a minimum, that is, there are no elements of negative norm. Otherwise, $| \cdot |_{val}: |a|_{val} = a$ works.

Comment: @user44191 yes, I like that. I will try to make it work with this and possibly some other assumptions. Perhaps $x, y \leq x + y$.

Comment: With $\Lambda=(\mathbb{R},+,\cdot)$, the map $\nu$ is not surjective.

Comment: Part of the definition can be summarized by saying that $\Lambda$ is an ordered commutative semiring (you probably want to assume some combatilbility between the ordering and the semiring structure). [Related](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/309712/valuation-with-values-in-a-semiring).